# Do I need CORS support in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 API for server to server communications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 API that has been in development for a while. In my Startup.cs, I have defined a CORS development policy as shown below;

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsDevPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Basically a wide open policy.

Now we are preparing for a production release and I want to make sure this is properly secured.

However, I do not have much experience with CORS and as I research the topic, I am wondering if I actually need to worry about restricting the CORS policy since my API is not actually being called directly from a web browser, but rather from a client application that uses HttpClient.

In addition, my API requires an OAuth2.0 access token so that only client applications I have registered in my Azure Active Directory can even access the API. So, do I need to worry about restricting my CORS policy in this scenario?

And if I do need to restrict my CORS policy, is the best way to restrict it is to add something like the following that includes a specific list of client domains for each site that will be accessing the API?

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsProdPolicy",
            builder => 
                builder.WithOrigins(
                          "https://client1.com", 
                          "https://client2.com",
                           ...
                           ...
                           ...   
                          "https://client100.com"
               )
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials());
    });
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You only need CORS if the website served from a domain accesses resources from another domain *through a browser*.  You also cannot allow any origin if credentials are provided (origins must be specified).

Comment: @As Amy Points out Cors,  Cors adds a header to the request, it's up to the browser to handle this. If you'd like to take additional measure to secure you're site, if it's you're own server calling your own server, you can additionally whitelist IP's if its, from a client computer, then your authorization should handle that

Comment: So, to confirm, the .NET Core HttpClient does not implement CORS like a modern browser does. So as long as I am not accessing the API via an actual  browser, CORS is not an issue?

Comment: CORS is a *browser-only* thing.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS  Count how many times it mentions "browsers".  It isn't needed for code-based HTTP access.

Comment: @Amy If you want to post this as an answer, I will give you the points

Comment: While it's perhaps not *currently* implemented in anything but browsers, that doesn't mean it won't be. It's a generic security policy, open to implementation by any client. It's not going to hurt anything to implement CORS, and when it is implemented by the client, you get extra security.

Comment: I have CORS added to my production project Startup.cs. Since it doesn't have any values in the .WithOrigins() filter, it is basically a deny all for browsers but if things change for the non-browser client applications, I can set the Origins header in the client and add the domain to the .WithOrigins filter at that time, yes?